When scrolling a chart, how do I find the x-values of the data points in view?
I have an app with dates along the x-axis. The user can select a date range for which data will be displayed. This date range can be moved along the x-axis by inputting a date for the date range. By knowing the position of the date range, I can adjust the y-axis position and resolution so that all data points within the range are in view.
Now I want to achieve the same functionality when scrolling the chart. This is my code so far:
Chart {
    ...
}
.chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
.chartScrollPosition(initialX: today)
.chartXVisibleDomain(length: range)

Scrolling works fine, but data points move in and out of view. If I knew which data points lie within the date range (chartXVisibleDomain), I could adjust the y-axis accordingly.
This is the reason for my question. Or are there other view modifiers that could accomplish this?

You know the length of the x axis (as you used .chartXVisibleDomain(length: range)). You can also know the current scroll position using chartScrollPosition(x:), so the visible range of X values is just all the values from scroll position to (scroll position + range).
And once you know the range of visible X values, you can use that to filter your data.
Here is an example:
struct ChartData: Identifiable {
    var id: Date { date }
    let date: Date
    let y: Double
}

let data = (1..<20).map { i in ChartData(
    date: Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: .now).addingTimeInterval(86400 * Double(i)),
    y: Double(i)
) }

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var scrollPos = Date()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Chart(data) { p in
                BarMark(x: .value("X", p.date, unit: .day), y: .value("Y", p.y))
            }
            .chartScrollPosition(x: $scrollPos)
            // two days visible at a time
            .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 86400 * 2)
            .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
            .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical, count: 2, spacing: 0)
            Text(scrollPos, format: .dateTime)

            // a list to show the visible Y values
            List {
                let visibleRange = scrollPos.addingTimeInterval(-86400)...scrollPos.addingTimeInterval(86400 * 2)
                let visibleData = data.filter { visibleRange.contains($0.date) }
                ForEach(visibleData) { p in Text(p.y, format: .number) }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Note that I subtracted another day from the lower bound of the visible range, because a part of the bar is still visible even if you scroll past the x coordinate of the bar. This is probably not necessary if you are using a line chart.
Another way is to "abuse" chartOverlay to get your hands on a ChartProxy, and get the x values through that. This allows you to get the max x value even without knowing the visible length of the x axis.
@State var minX = Date()
@State var maxX = Date()
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Chart(data) { p in
            BarMark(x: .value("X", p.date, unit: .day), y: .value("Y", p.y))
        }
        .chartXVisibleDomain(length: 86400 * 2)
        .chartScrollableAxes(.horizontal)
        .chartOverlay { chart in
            GeometryReader { geo in
                if let anchor = chart.plotFrame {
                    let frame = geo[anchor]
                    if let minX = chart.value(atX: -frame.minX, as: Date.self),
                       let maxX = chart.value(atX: -frame.minX + geo.size.width, as: Date.self) {
                        Color.clear
                            .onChange(of: minX, initial: true) { _, newValue in
                                self.minX = newValue.addingTimeInterval(-86400)
                            }
                            .onChange(of: maxX, initial: true) { _, newValue in
                                self.maxX = newValue
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .containerRelativeFrame(.vertical, count: 2, spacing: 0)
        Text(minX, format: .dateTime)
        List {
            let visibleRange = minX...maxX
            let visibleData = data.filter { visibleRange.contains($0.date) }
            ForEach(visibleData) { p in Text(p.y, format: .number) }
        }
    }
    .padding()
}

